# Combined iteration over lined up enumerables in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, iteration, enumerable

Is there a way to do `foreach` style iteration over lined up enumerables in C#?  For subscriptable lists, I know one could use a regular `for` loop iterating an int over the index range, but I really prefer `foreach` to `for` for a number of reasons.

Bonus points if it works in C# 2.0.

**Clarification:** I am talking about multiple lined up enumerables. Like arrays of pencils and papers. I want each pencil to write on the corresponding paper.

**Note:** Originally this question used the term *parallel* instead of *lined up*.

Comment: wouldn't  a for loop be a more simpler, shorter, readable solution instead of the Combine response below ? what are your reasons for preferring foreach in this case

Comment: Also parallel iteration just surfaced in Ruby 1.9 so I'd bet on it not being in C# as of now.. LISP had it though :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Are you trying to iterate over multiple enumerables in parallel, or are you trying to loop over one enumerable, processing different items in parallel?

Comment: I am talking about multiple enumerables in parallel.  Like parallel arrays of pencils and papers.  I want each pencil to write on the corresponding paper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer, no. `foreach` works on only one enumerable at a time.

However, if you combine your parallel enumerables into a single one, you can `foreach` over the combined. I am not aware of any easy, built in method of doing this, but the following should work (though I have not tested it):

```
public IEnumerable<TSource[]> Combine<TSource>(params object[] sources)
{
    foreach(var o in sources)
    {
        // Choose your own exception
        if(!(o is IEnumerable<TSource>)) throw new Exception();
    }

    var enums =
        sources.Select(s => ((IEnumerable<TSource>)s).GetEnumerator())
        .ToArray();

    while(enums.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
    {
        yield return enums.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can `foreach` over the returned enumerable:

```
foreach(var v in Combine(en1, en2, en3))
{
    // Remembering that v is an array of the type contained in en1,
    // en2 and en3.
}
```

Comment: Why did you pick object[] instead of IEnumerable<TSource> as parameter type? It would eliminate the exception, no?

Comment: There was at least one version of the C# language that wouldn't compile params with anything other than object[]. Considering this answer is five years old, I'd guess the only version I'd used at that point was one that wouldn't work with `params IEnumerable<TSource>[] sources`. These days, of course I'd use the more explicit typing. I'd probably also use the `IEnumerable<T>.Zip` extension method for two enumerables - fairly sure this also didn't exist five years ago.

Answer (score 10):

.NET 4's BlockingCollection makes this pretty easy. Create a BlockingCollection, return its .GetConsumingEnumerable() in the enumerable method. Then the foreach simply adds to the blocking collection.

E.g.

```
private BlockingCollection<T> m_data = new BlockingCollection<T>();

public IEnumerable<T> GetData( IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources )
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ParallelGetData( sources ) );
    return m_data.GetConsumingEnumerable();
}

private void ParallelGetData( IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources )
{
    foreach( var source in sources )
    {
        foreach( var item in source )
        {
            m_data.Add( item );
        };
    }

    //Adding complete, the enumeration can stop now
    m_data.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Hope this helps.
BTW I [posted a blog about this](http://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2009/11/blockingcollection-parallel-yields.html) last night

Andre

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about enumerating multiple enumerables together.

Answer (score 3):

Zooba's answer is good, but you might also want to look at the answers to ["How to iterate over two arrays at once"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496704).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an implementation of EachParallel() from the .NET4 Parallel library.  It is compatible with .NET 3.5:  [Parallel ForEach Loop in C# 3.5](http://blog.robvolk.com/2009/06/parallel-foreach-loop-in-c-35.html)
Usage:

```
string[] names = { "cartman", "stan", "kenny", "kyle" };
names.EachParallel(name =>
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
    catch { /* handle exception */ }
});
```

Implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates through each item in a list in parallel
/// </summary>
public static void EachParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    // enumerate the list so it can't change during execution
    list = list.ToArray();
    var count = list.Count();

    if (count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        // if there's only one element, just execute it
        action(list.First());
    }
    else
    {
        // Launch each method in it's own thread
        const int MaxHandles = 64;
        for (var offset = 0; offset < list.Count() / MaxHandles; offset++)
        {
            // break up the list into 64-item chunks because of a limitiation             // in WaitHandle
            var chunk = list.Skip(offset * MaxHandles).Take(MaxHandles);

            // Initialize the reset events to keep track of completed threads
            var resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[chunk.Count()];

            // spawn a thread for each item in the chunk
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in chunk)
            {
                resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object data) =>
                {
                    int methodIndex = (int)((object[])data)[0];

                    // Execute the method and pass in the enumerated item
                    action((T)((object[])data)[1]);

                    // Tell the calling thread that we're done
                    resetEvents[methodIndex].Set();
                }), new object[] { i, item });
                i++;
            }

            // Wait for all threads to execute
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the `EachParallel` extension method is obsolete after the introduction of the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class and the [`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) operator in .NET Framework 4.0 (April 2010).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to the basics - I rewrote the currently accepted answer in a simpler way:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> Combine<TSource> (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> sources)
    {
        var enums = sources
            .Select (s => s.GetEnumerator ())
            .ToArray ();

        while (enums.All (e => e.MoveNext ())) {
            yield return enums.Select (e => e.Current).ToArray ();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> Combine<TSource> (params IEnumerable<TSource>[] sources)
    {
        return sources.Combine ();
    }
```

Comment: Ideally the enumerators should be disposed after the enumeration.

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you?

```
public static class Parallel
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T>[] sources,
                                  Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var enumerable in sources)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(source => {
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<T>)source)
                    action(item);
            }, enumerable);
        }
    }
}

// sample usage:
static void Main()
{
    string[] s1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
    string[] s2 = { "4", "5", "6" };
    IEnumerable<string>[] sources = { s1, s2 };
    Parallel.ForEach(sources, s => Console.WriteLine(s));
    Thread.Sleep(0); // allow background threads to work
}
```

For C# 2.0, you need to convert the lambda expressions above to delegates.

Note: This utility method uses background threads. You may want to modify it to use foreground threads, and probably you'll want to wait till all threads finish. If you do that, I suggest you create `sources.Length - 1` threads, and use the current executing thread for the last (or first) source.

(I wish I could include waiting for threads to finish in my code, but I'm sorry that I don't know how to do that yet. I guess you should use <del>a `WaitHandle`</del> `Thread.Join()`.)