# Processing records in parallel in .NET 2.0 using multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-2.0

I need to process the records available in the table in parallel using multithreading. I am using C# and targeting .NET 2.0.

I know that I can use `Parallel.ForEach` in .NET 4.0 to do this, but I'm not sure how to achieve it using .NET 2.0.

Comment: Since Tasks are not available either in .NET 2, you'll have to fall back on threads to get what you want, you may want to read about the `System.Threading` Namespace : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523194/parallel-iteration-in-c

Comment: @Olivarsham nice find, combined with threads, the OP may get what he wants

Comment: paraallel foreach in .NET 4.0 is really a bad idea - an abuse of the API. This is meant for heavy processing tasks, not for IO heavy tasks.

Comment: Give us some numeric. How many items? I see a lot of answers that are totally unsuitable the moment you process 10 million records (or anything more than a dozen or two) because they will overload the CPU without caring about the IO.

Comment: @TomTom I don't see anywhere OP mentioned IO. Yes I do agree that using threads for IO is just lack of understanding of IO but I don't see it in question.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other requirements, multithreading can be implemented by defining a function

```
static void Function()
{
    // do some work here
}
```

which is then used as the entry point for a different thread by

```
Thread iThread = new Thread(Function);
```

and

```
iThread.Start();
```

is a non-blocking call starting the other thread.

Comment: @codor- What if I want to call function with a parameter?

Comment: To my understanding, passing parameters as agruments is impossible; you would have to use static fields to pass and return information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your own implementation `Parallel.Foreach` using [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx) and [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public class Parallel
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        var resetEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((i) =>
            {
                action((T)i);
                evt.Set();
            }, item);
            resetEvents.Add(evt);
        }

        foreach (var re in resetEvents)
            re.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Here is the [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/implementation-of-parallel-foreach-for-net-3-5)

Comment: Use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` instead of `WaitOne` in a loop to avoid unnecessary wakeups.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to .Net 4.0 recommended way to achieve parallelism is "ThreadPool" unless you have a special use case.

For example, if you need a "Foreground Thread" or STA thread, you use Thread class directly. Otherwise, always the answer is ThreadPool.

You consume ThreadPool by calling [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

However `QueueUserWorkItem` doesn't provide any way to wait for the completion. If you want to wait for the completion, you can use [Delegate.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns an `IAsyncResult`(rough equivalent of Task before .Net 4.0) which allows you to wait for the completion and lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in my [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334178/limit-threads-count/3338305#3338305) that shows how to launch threads and manage how many are running at one time. That ought to give you a framework to start with.