# IEnumerable of averages of one property from IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> where T has two properties

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomObject>>`s where `CustomObject` has an `x` (which is used like a key (in this case `1`, `2`, `3`)) and a `y` value. Some pretend data:

```
{
  { {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8} }, 
  { {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4,-2} },
  { {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 0}, {4, 0} }
}
```

What is the best way I can retrieve the following `IEnumerable<CustomObject>`:

`{ {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2} }`

I.e. the average of the `y` values for each element.

Performance needs to be reasonable, so no `.ToList()` or similar can be used. I've been trying various things with LINQ but to no avail.

### Update

@Bort, @Rawling, I've tested your answers and @Rawling's is very slightly faster. @Bort's answer, however, is more readable so I think I will go with that for the moment. Please feel free to keep answers coming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can flatten out the list of lists with `SelectMany`, then `GroupBy` x and `Select` the average:

```
var averages = customObjectLists
    .SelectMany(l => l)
    .GroupBy(co => co.x)
    .Select(g => new CustomObject { x => g.Key, y = g.Average(co => co.y) });
```

Comment: Does `GroupBy` not count as calling `ToList()` - it does solidify the whole data set.

Comment: If you are calculating averages you **need** to iterate through the whole dataset - else you cannot calculate the average.

Comment: Yes you need to iterate through it all, but it doesn't mean you need to load it all into memory at once.

Comment: Where does it say that GroupBy loads the whole dataset?

Comment: @Maarten: It does. Use reflector and you'll see it putting each element into an array. Use this code on infinite sequences and you'll get an `OutOfMemoryException` before you get any results. Think about it and you'll see you can't get an average across a group unless you know there aren't any more elements in the input that go in that group - and you can't know that until the input is exhausted, and you need to have stored all the elements from other groups somewhere.

Comment: @Maarten (I'd like to retract that last "think about it" point, obviously from your first comment you know that.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you the results you're looking for. It will flatten out the list of lists into a single `List<CustomObject>`, and then group by the `X` value and average the `Y` value, leaving you with an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type with `X` and `Y` properties. You can change the `select new {} ...` to call a constructor for `CustomObject`, and you will get an `IEnumerable<CustomObject>`.

```
var myComplexObject = //your IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomObject>>
var result = from firstList in myComplexObject
        from secondList in firstList
        group secondList by secondList.X into grp
        select new {X = grp.Key, Y = (int)grp.Average(p=>p.Y)};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind solidifying the *outer* enumerator, the following LINQy method will defer execution of the *inner* enumerators.

```
IEnumerable<V> AggregateAcross<T, U, V>(
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input,
            Func<T, U> select,
            Func<IEnumerable<U>, V> aggregate)
    {
        var enumerators = input.Select(ie => ie.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            yield return aggregate(enumerators.Select(e => select(e.Current)));
        }
    }
```

Call as e.g.

```
foreach (var avg in AggregateAcross(
                     input,
                     pair => pair.y,
                     e => e.Average(y => y)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(avg);
}
```

Note that this stops as soon as one of the inner enumerators runs out of elements. Also, it needs something to dispose all the enumerators when you're done. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989319/zip-n-ienumerablets-together-iterate-over-them-simultaneously) for further ideas.

(Also note that this is completely ignoring the `x` values. As all your inputs are in order, and your desired output is also in order, the `x` values don't add anything.)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test it, but I think this should work.

```
public void Test() {
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<CustomObject>> data = ...;
    var result = data
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .GroupBy(
            item => item.x,
            (key, r) => new { x = key, data = r.Select(z => z.y) }
        )
        .Select(x => new CustomObject { x = x.x, y = (int)x.data.Average() })
        .ToList();
}
```