# using foreach to iterate simultaneously through multiple lists (syntax sugar)

Tags: c#, .net

Hi is there a way to do things like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.Count, b.Count); i++)
{
    // Do stuff
    //a[i]
    //b[i]
}
```

with Foreach?

because it would be nice to write something like

```
foreach(var item1 in list1 and var item2 in list2 /* ....*/)
{
   item1.use(item2);
}
```

## EDIT

ok sorry i wasn't clear enough for some people so here am hopefully better explanation

```
List<classA> listA = fillListA();
List<classB> listB = fillListB();
//here could be infinity many lists of sometimes diffrent T types
```

Now i want to perform some sort of **ForEach** because i dont like to do it with a **for** loop
it should be simple and clear well something like

```
foreach(var item1 in list1 and var item2 in list2 /* and ...*/)
{
    item1.use(item2);
}
```

AFAIK i cant modifie such a keay word class thing 
so i thought ok build the iterator like [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) did `ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Action<TSource>)` 
but her i get stucked because i don't know how implement it

```
Static.ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>,IEnumerable<TSource>, ???Action<TSource,???>????)
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do what `foreach` does under the hood, but with two enumerators:

```
using(var e1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
using(var e2 = list2.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
    {
         var item1 = e1.Current;
         var item2 = e2.Current;

         // use item1 and item2
    }
}
```

For convenience, you can write an extension method like the following that takes an action:

```
public static void ZipDo<T1, T2>( this IEnumerable<T1> first, IEnumerable<T2> second, Action<T1, T2> action)
{
    using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
        {
            action(e1.Current, e2.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
list1.ZipDo(list2, (i1,i2) => i1.Use(i2));
```

---

By the way, you can expand this to use 3 or more lists:

```
public static void ZipDo<T1, T2, T3>(this IEnumerable<T1> first,
    IEnumerable<T2> second, IEnumerable<T3> third,
    Action<T1, T2, T3> action)
{
    using (var e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    using (var e3 = third.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext() && e3.MoveNext())
        {
            action(e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

The approach above is required when the collections have *different* generic types. However, if they all have the *same* generic type, then you can write a flexible method that takes any number of `IEnumerable<T>`s:

```
public static void ZipAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> all, Action<IEnumerable<T>> action)
{
    var enumerators = all.Select(e => e.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
    try
    {
        while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
            action(enumerators.Select(e => e.Current));
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var e in enumerators) 
            e.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
var lists = new[] {
     new[]{ 1, 1, 1 }, 
     new[]{ 2, 2, 2 }, 
     new[]{ 3, 3, 3 }};

lists.ZipAll(nums => Console.WriteLine(nums.Sum()));
// 6
// 6
// 6
```

Comment: does your answer has some advantages agains Ani's answer ?

Comment: @WiiMaxx you could expand this approach for 3 or more list (see edit), but if you just need to zip 2 lists, they're about the same -- there is practically no performance or readability difference.

Comment: What if one list is shorter than the other one? Won't it stop to iterrate?

Comment: @Kris Sorry I noticed your question late. Yes, it will stop iterating, which is generally what you want and is consistent with Linq's Zip method. However, if you want to continue, you could replace "&& MoveNext" with "|| MoveNext".  Then, you'd need to decide on what to use for the completed enumerator's current item, e.g. use default(T).

Answer (score 30):

The only thing I can think of that comes close is [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) along with [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
foreach(var tuple in list1.Zip(list2, Tuple.Create))
{
    tuple.Item1.use(tuple.Item2);
}
```

Of course, if instead of `use`, we had a non side-effecting method that produced a third value from the two elements, you could do:

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (item1, item2) => item1.ProduceObject(item2))
                  .ToList(); // if required
```

Comment: so there is no way to create some sort of `action` ? i thought there could be a way to write something like the `Parallel.Foreach()`

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using Parallel.ForEach here instead of the language foreach. Sorry, am I missing something?

Comment: nono i mean in Parallel.Foreach you can write it like Parallel.ForEach(list, item=>{//dostuff}) where first param = ienmum, second param = action. so i thought i could maybe write a function like `StaticClass.ForEach(Ienum,ienum, ???someaction???)`

Comment: You mean: `Parallel.ForEach(list1.Zip(list2, Tuple.Create), tuple =>  tuple.Item1.use(tuple.Item2));` Bear in mind that this only parallelizes the invocation of the actions, not the enumeration of the sources or zipping them together.

Comment: `public static void ForEach<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> source1, IEnumerable<T2> source2, Action<T1, T2> body) { foreach (var tuple in source1.Zip(source2, Tuple.Create)) { body(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2); } }` ?

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Oh, I misunderstood your comment. Yes, do what Corak suggests.

Comment: @Corak that should better be an answer

Comment: @Ani is there a way to Zip more than 2 lists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989319/zip-n-ienumerablets-together-iterate-over-them-simultaneously

Comment: @WiiMaxx - I just put Anis answer into a method. And Erens approach is more flexible.

Comment: In this case I think I prefer `Enumerable.Zip(list1, list2, Tuple.Create)`.

Answer (score 5):

You could also simply use a local integer variable if the lists have the same length:

```
List<classA> listA = fillListA();
List<classB> listB = fillListB();

var i = 0;
foreach(var itemA in listA)
{
    itemA.use(listB[i++]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method (though only available in .net 4 and above) something like this?

```
List<int> l4 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<int> l5 = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7 };

var l4Andl5 = l4.Zip(l5, (l, m) => new { List1 = l, List2 = m });
foreach (var x in l4Andl5)
{


}
```

Comment: no not exactly because typeof(a) != typeof(b) and it could also exist a list c,d,...

Comment: types don't matter here, second list can be of type string.