# Using foreach with two types of conditions in c#

Tags: c#, foreach

I used dropdown for search. The text value should different from the value. So, I created 2 types of methods:

```
    List<string> lstRoles = new List<string>();
    lstRoles = _repository.GetRolesForFindJobseekers();
    List<string> lstFunctions = new List<string>();
    lstFunctions = _repository.GetFunctionsForRolesFindJobSeekers();


    List<SelectListItem> selectListRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();

    int i = 1;
    foreach (string role in lstRoles)
    {

            selectListRoles.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = role,
                Value = role,
                Selected = (i == 0)
            });

            i++;

    }
    ViewData["RolesForJobSeekers"] = selectListRoles;
```

`lstFunctions` should come in the value field. How will I add this?

Comment: maybe you can use a list of KeyValuePair where key is role and value is function?

Comment: how do you know which "role" goes with which "function"?

Comment: that depends on how you use your RolesForJobSeekers view data, if it is required by some framework you are using, name it so others can help, or consult it documentation. This is more than how to use that framework, than a c# foreach

Comment: if you're asking how to iterate two lists in parallel, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18396163/201088).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first combine these 2 lists into one and then loop over that list.

```
var lstCombined =
    lstRoles
     .Zip(lstFunctions, (role, function) => new {Role = role, Function = function}).ToList();

int i = 1;

foreach (var item in lstCombined)
{
    selectListRoles.Add(new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = item.Role,
                                Value = item.Function,
                                Selected = (i == 0)
                            });

    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use linq and get it done in one query:

```
var selectListRoles =
    lstRoles
        .Zip(lstFunctions, (role, function) => new { role, function })
        .Select((rf, i) => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = rf.role,
            Value = rf.function,
            Selected = (i + 1 == 0),
        })
        .ToList();

ViewData["RolesForJobSeekers"] = selectListRoles;
```

Comment: +1 my idea but sooner. The source enumerables don't need to be lists at all.

Comment: Ta. It's better if they are a list or an array. That ensures that the enumerable is executed once so that you don't get side effects.

Comment: depends on the rest of the code, avoid multiple enumerations.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of foreach you can use enumerators to iterate over the two list in the same time

```
IEnumerator enum1 = lstRoles.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator enum2 = lstFunctions.GetEnumerator();

int i = 1;
while ((enum1.MoveNext()) && (enum2.MoveNext()))
{
        selectListRoles.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = enum1.Current,
            Value = enum2.Current,
            Selected = (i == 0)
        });

        i++;
}
```

Comment: you should use `using` for the enumerators.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
var selectListRoles = _repository.GetRolesForFindJobseekers().Zip(
    _repository.GetFunctionsForRolesFindJobSeekers(),
    (role, function) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = role,
            Value = function,
            Selected = false
        }).ToList();
selectListRoles[0].Selected = true;
ViewData["RolesForJobSeekers"] = selectListRoles;
```

---

If you didn't want to instantiate `selectListRoles`

```
// If you know selectListRoles starts empty, use 0 instead of baseIndex.
var baseIndex = selectListRoles.Count;
selectListRoles.AddRange(_repository.GetRolesForFindJobseekers().Zip(
    _repository.GetFunctionsForRolesFindJobSeekers(),
    (role, function) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = role,
            Value = function,
            Selected = false
        }));
selectListRoles[baseIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: It's a bad idea closing over an external variable in a query. You get the wrong results if the query is executed multiple times.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I agree, its a dirty, and wasteful hack.

Comment: Now that's a better solution for this situation. I like it.