# How do I merge these two tables with two Models?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I use two foreach's on one table, or another method to get my count and total together?

This is the table:

```
<div style="padding-top: 30px">
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Date1.Reverse())
        {
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.theDate) </td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.theCount) </td>
                </tr>
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model.Date2.Reverse())
        {
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.theCount) </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

This is how I'm calling the models:

```
    public class QueryView
    {
        public IEnumerable<Date1> Date1 { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Date1> Date2 { get; set; }
    }
}
@model CWebPortal.Models.QueryView
```

This is what is displayed:
[image: table]

I want that Total to be on the same line of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list in parallel.

hope these links will help

1. [iterate simultaneously through multiple list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395943/using-foreach-to-iterate-simultaneously-through-multiple-lists-syntax-sugar)
2. [Iterate two Lists or Arrays with one ForEach statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statement-in-c-sharp)

`@using (var e1 = Model.Date1.Reverse().GetEnumerator())
    {
      using (var e2 = Model.Date2.Reverse().GetEnumerator())
      {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
        {
             var item1 = e1.Current;
             var item2 = e2.Current;  
             
                  item1.theDate 
                  item1.theCount 
                  item2.theCount 
             
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: It removed my formatting for theDate:  `[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` How do I get it back?

Comment: @StemStep formate in razor view using ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy")

Comment: Yeah @Shamseer, I needed .Value.toString.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your two `foreach` loops into one `for` loop and use the same index for both `IEnumerables`. That's probably the first, and simplest, step to correcting the issue.

As a second step, I'd suggest looking for ways to rewrite this Model. If these three pieces of data are related this closely, then there's plenty of reason for you to create a new object that contains all the data.

Lastly, the View reversing the order of the items in the `IEnumerables` strikes me as a code smell. This kind of newest-to-oldest sorting, particularly done across two enumerable objects, could easily be in the Model as well.

Comment: How do I rewrite the model so the data is together?

Comment: We'd need way more detail to answer that question. Start with your data source - those three columns came from somewhere, so try to rewrite the code that retrieves the data so that all three columns go into one object.

Answer (score 0):

In the model, you can add another list with a class Table, which will have all three values. Something like below.

```
public IEnumerable<Table> TableLst { get; set; }

public class Table
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}
```

As you have two lists Date1 and Date2, you can easily join these based on dates using LINQ and pass it in the controller.

```
 var data = qv.Date1.Join(qv.Date2, d1 => d1.theDate, d2 => d2.theDate, (d1, d2) => new { d1, d2 });

        qv.Table = data.Select(t => new Table
        {
            Date = t.d1.theDate,
            count = t.d1.theCount,
            total = t.d2.theCount

        });

        return View(qv);
```

You can also perform order by on the TableLst in the controller and pass it to model. After which only one for loop would be easy to get the data

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.TableLst)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date) </td>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.count) </td>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.total) </td>
           </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an intermidiate viewModel class to group the data.

e.g.

```
public class QueryViewModel
{
    public DateTime displayDate {get; set;}
    public int Count1 {get; set;}
    public int count2 {get; set;}
}

 public class QueryView
 {
    public IEnumerable<QueryViewModel> DateList =new IEnumerable<QueryViewModel>();
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Date1> Date2 { get; set; }

    public  fillDates()
    {
       QueryViewModel qvm=new QueryViewModel()          
       int i=0;
       foreach(var item in Date1.Reverse())
       {
          qvm.displayDate = theDate;
          qvm.Count1  = theCount;
         DateList.Add(qvm);
       }

       int i=0;
       foreach(var item in Date2.Reverse())
       {
          DateList[i].Count2  = theCount;
          i++;
       }

       return DateList
    }
 }
```

Use fillDates() in your view to render the list.

Comment: I dont get how to get that to work. Creating the QueryViewModel.

Comment: Implementation is given in the above code. when you will get the final list queryViewModel.fillDates() function.

Comment: Do I have to create another class called QueryViewModel with above in it?

Comment: yes, sorry it was not properly formated, i've reformatted the code. please have a look

Comment: Hey @Pandey, that is what I had, but I got this error: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IEnumerable<QueryViewModel>'

Comment: In, 
    public IEnumerable<QueryViewModel> DateList =new IEnumerable<QueryViewModel>();

Replace IEnumerable with List

i.e.
 
    public List<QueryViewModel> DateList =new List<QueryViewModel>();