# Is it possible to iterate over two containers?

Tags: c#, .net, iteration

I have the following code:

```
        List<Point> xyData = new List<Point>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xdata.Length;i++ )
        {
            xyData.Add(new Point(xdata[i], ydata[i]));
        }
```

I want to iterate simultaneously over **xdata** and **ydata**, which have the same length

Now, I can add another counter,

```
        int i=0;
        List<Point> xyData = new List<Point>();
        foreach (double x in xdata){
            var  y = ydata[i];
            xyData.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
```

But I want to write something like this (Pseudo code, does not compile)

```
        List<Point> xyData = new List<Point>();
        foreach (double x in xdata, double y in ydata){
            xyData.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve what I want?

**Edit:**

I meant that I want to get a list like this:
[x0,y0],[x1,y1],[x2,y2].
Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Maybe you need to merge these two list into one and iterate on that one?

Comment: @iamsta - The OP _is_ merging the 2 arrays.

Comment: I know, i am suggesting using Zip method with or ZIP algorithm in point

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate over two arrays at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496704/how-to-iterate-over-two-arrays-at-once)

Comment: @WladimirPalant, it is not. I checked this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ.

If you want the Carthesian product (x1,y1) (x1,y2) (x2,y1) (x2,y2)

```
var xyData = xData.SelectMany(yData,(x,y)=>new Point(x,y)).ToList();
```

If you want the merged list (x1,y1) (x2,y2)

```
var xyData = xData.Zip(yData,(x,y)=>new Point(x,y)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first option is absolutely fine - a good way to achieve this.

If you can use LINQ, you can join the two collections together using the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method:

```
var points = xdata.Zip(ydata, (x, y) => new Point(x, y));
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?
Notice the Index in the arrays

```
    List<Point> xyData = new List<Point>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xdata.Length;i++ )
    {
        xyData.Add(new Point(xdata[i], ydata[i]));
    }
```

Comment: IamStalker - yes, that would be a limitation of wanting to iterate over two containers at once

Comment: @IamStalker OP mentioned both lists have the same length.